# Twig add space at camel case letter

Tags: symfony, twig

Is there a way in Twig to add a space where the word has camel case letters.

> For instance: helloWorldHowAreYouDoing would be **hello World How Are You Doing**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create [Twig Extension](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html) and create a function to do that.

Something like this would do it..

```
/**
 * Convert under_score to title Case
 *
 * @param $underscore
 * @return string
 */
public static function convertUnderscoreToTitleCase($underscore)
{
    return preg_replace('/(?:^|_)(.?)/e', "strtoupper(' $1')", $underscore);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**From php version 5.5 the [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) function is required as the "/e" modifier is now deprecated.**

Create an extension method and call it from the twig page as a filter.

Extension Class:

```
<?php

// src/AppBundle/Twig/AppExtension.php
namespace AppBundle\Twig;

class yourExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('camelToSpace', array($this, 'convertCamelCaseToHaveSpacesFilter')),
        );
    }

    /*
     * Converts camel case string to have spaces
     */
    public function convertCamelCaseToHaveSpacesFilter($camelCaseString)
    {

        $pattern = '/(([A-Z]{1}))/';
        return preg_replace_callback(
            $pattern,
            function ($matches) {return " " .$matches[0];},
            $camelCaseString
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_extension';
    }
}
```

Where the function convertCamelCaseToHaveSpacesFilter will do the work if you pass it a camel case string.

In Twig page:

```
<body>
    {% set yourString = 'helloWorldHowAreYouDoing' %}
    {{ yourString|camelToSpace }}
</body>
```

This should also work for Pascal casing but it may require triming the string afterwards.

If autowiring is not enabled, remember to register your extension class. In services.yml:

```
services:
    app.twig_extension:
        class: RouteToExtensionClass\yourExtension
        public: false
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not there out of the box. You can create twig extension to do that:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html